# calling multiple dataframe column names to build a new dataframe keyerror

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After one-hot encoding 2 different features, then joining the resulting one-hot encoded columns with the original dataframe in Pandas, I have a 3 dataframes.

The first is OneHotZips (which contains my one-hot encoded feature #1).
The second is OneHotYearBuilt (same thing, i.e. my feature #2 as one hot encoded columns in a dataframe). 
Last, I have subset, which is the previous two joined with the original dataframe. More concretely, subset.keys() is:

```
Index(['lat_z', 'lon_z', 'price_z', 'lot_z', 'LotSizeSquareFeet',
       'TotalBedrooms', 'NormalizedBathCount', 'PropertyAddressLatitude',
       'PropertyAddressLongitude', 'MonthsToSale',
       ...
       'year_built_2008.0', 'year_built_2009.0', 'year_built_2010.0',
       'year_built_2011.0', 'year_built_2012.0', 'year_built_2013.0',
       'year_built_2014.0', 'year_built_2015.0', 'year_built_2016.0',
       'year_built_2017.0'],
      dtype='object', length=477)
```

I would like to use only some of these columns in a new dataframe, called downsampled_z.

I have been able to get a string of strings? with

```
'"' + '", "'.join(list(OneHotZips.columns.values)) + '"'
```

It looks like:

```
'"year_built_1882.0", "year_built_1900.0", ... "year_built_2017.0"'
```

Which seems to be the way I want it, but the following doesn't work:

```
downsampled_z = subset[["lat_z", "lon_z", "price_z", "lot_z", "TotalBedrooms", "NormalizedBathCount", "built_prct", 
 '"' + '", "'.join(list(OneHotZips.columns.values)) + '"',
 '"' + '", "'.join(list(OneHotYearBuilt.columns.values)) + '"']]
```

This results in a keyerror of

```
'[\'"year_built_1882.0", "year_built_1900.0", ... "year_built_2017.0"\'] not in index
```

Other approaches I have taken such as

```
[str(x) for x in list(OneHotZips.columns.values)]
```

result in

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are really creating one long string, which is not your column name. You can just use:

```
downsampled_cols = ["lat_z", "lon_z", "price_z", "lot_z", "TotalBedrooms", "NormalizedBathCount", "built_prct"] +\
list(OneHotZips.columns.values) +\
list(OneHotYearBuilt.columns.values) +\
...
```

And then,

```
downsampled_z = subset[downsampled_cols]
```

If you join a list of strings, you end up with a single string.

---

I think your confusion is basically due to something else. In Python, the `print` statement does not show the type of the variable. That is, if you `print('abc')` you will get `abc` (without quotes), and `print(123)` will give you `123` (also without quotes). If you use `repr` instead, you would see the quotes, or lack thereof. But it can get confusing that way. What I mean to say is [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Don't worry about explicitly seeing quotes in your output. If there is a letter in your variable value, then the variable type is `string`. You can, of course, store numbers as strings, which is where there could be some confusion.